# Using Pandas df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame of a csv file which is being read by pandas. What I am attempting to do is use df.loc to add a new column but only insert values into the column when values from another column, called "SKU" end with "-RF" and "-NEW".

The code I was working on is below. It has the csv file being read, "original_file", and then two .loc commands. ONE new column called "Cond" is supposed to be being added, and I want "NEW" to be added to that column where the value in the 'SKU' column ends with "-NEW" and "USED" to be added to the new column where the 'SKU' ends with "-RF".

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

This is the error I have been getting on it.

```
original_file = pd.read_csv('wc-product-export-20-9-2022-1663680891149.csv')

original_file.loc[['SKU'].str.endswith("-RF"),'Cond'] = 'USED'
original_file.loc[['SKU'].str.endswith("-NEW"),'Cond'] = 'NEW'
```

Comment: `['SKU'].str` raises the error. The list `['SKU']` doesn't have an attribute `str`. Did you mean `original_file['SKU'].str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with adding the df when you call column by name

```
original_file.loc[original_file['SKU'].str.endswith("-RF"),'Cond'] = 'USED'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Just wanted to add in case somebody comes across this and needs to solve the same problem as me: Just before this code, I had to add " original_file = original_file.astype(str) " , otherwise it was erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for. You can use the apply function to check every cell in the SKU column and insert into the new column accordingly.

```
original_file['NEWCOL'] = original_file['SKU'].apply(
    lambda x: 'USED' if x.endswith('-RF') else 'NEW' if x.endswith('-NEW') else None)
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to give this it's own name in order to be able to print it and make sure it's worked? Tried surrounding it parentheses, but of course it's not going to let it be that easy haha

Comment: To test it you can just print(original_file). To rename the new column you just change the first string "NEWCOL" to whatever you want.